# xamarin android binding how to change method argument type

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

java code:

```
public void setPicker(List<List<T>> options2Items)
```

How to write the Metadata.xml file to change the `List<List<T>>`  to .net's strong type.
because when I place a .net object for example:`List<List<string>>`,vs will thorw error for me

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.IList>'
```

Comment: You binding a Java library and want change its method argument type?

Comment: yes,do you know how to do this ?

Comment: It did has a `Metadata.xml` could do this, for more information, you could read the document :   [Java Bindings Metadata](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#Overview).

Comment: could you please share your Java library? I will try to resolve this problem.